# How make a requete in controller in condition datetime

Tags: symfony

i need to display the list of demands between date1 and date2:this is the code in my controller:

```
$finsemaine=new \DateTime('now');  
      $finsemaine = new \DateTime('20:00:00');
      $daysToMove = (int)($finsemaine->format('N')) - 1;


                    if ($daysToMove)
                    {
                         $finsemaine->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . $daysToMove . 'D'));
                    }
                        $finsemaine->format('Y-m-d '); 
                        $finsemaine->modify('+5 day');

//debut semaine
       $debut=new \DateTime('now');  
                         $debut = new \DateTime('08:00:00');

                        $daysToMove = (int)($debut->format('N')) - 1;


                    if ($daysToMove)
                    {
                        $debut->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . $daysToMove . 'D'));
                    }
                        $debut->format('Y-m-d ');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Appointement')->findBy(array('therapist'=>$user));
```

i have a element in datebase table :datestart (datetime) and i need to display demands between $debut and $finsemaine.Can someone help me to fix this requete.And think's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a custom request in AppointementRepository.php:

```
public function findAppointementInTimeFrame($user, \DateTime $debut, \DateTime $finsemaine)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('a')
       ->from('PublishDemandsBundle:Appointement','a')
       ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
             $qb->expr()->gt('a.datestart', ':debut'),
             $qb->expr()->lt('a.dateStart', ':finsemaine'),
             $qb->expr()->eq('a.therapist', ':therapist'),
             ))
       ->setParameter('debut', $debut)
       ->setParameter('finsemaine', $finsemaine);
       ->setParameter('therapist', $user);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: and how can i add the condition of findBy(array('therapist'=>$user));

Comment: Yeah I forgot that. See my edited answer. I guess you are French, so I suggest you have a look at this tutorial because you probably will need to do such kind of things by yourself in future: [Tuto Openclassroom](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/les-methodes-de-recuperation-personnelles)